# use polycode C++ api in netbeans project

Tags: c++, netbeans, frameworks, polycode

I'm new to C++ (and Netbeans). I wanted to use a framework for drawing in my project, I came across Polycode (which has a C++ api) - I thought it would be good to learn to use such a framework for future as well.
[Polycode website](http://polycode.org/)

Any way, I tried to copy and include files from the core directory on their github repository, but it doesn't seem to be that simple.
Could somebody guide me on how I should use this library in a Netbeans C++ project?

Comment: The polycode documentation is a good start: http://polycode.org/tutorial/

Comment: @DavidKernin it doesn't provide what i'm looking for really. It doesn't event tell which files should I copy to my project/any specific place that netbeans wants me to.